# How make to wait for the completion of LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - Java

Tags: java, mariadb

When I import a .csv file I need to wait for the loading to complete, but when performing the executeUpdate, a value is returned without the data from the local load data infile being completed.

```
String query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + pathToFile + "' INTO TABLE phones FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' "
+ "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (id_phone, phone)";
var rowsAffected = em.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What value is returned?

Comment: Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM phones` to find the number of rows.